# Java Custom Exception Criteria

Tags: java, exception

Quick question, I'm having a bit of a hard time wrapping my head around how exceptions catching works. I understand you could nest an exception in an if statement i.e

```
int i = 0;
if (i == 0) {
  throw new Exception("i cannot be 0");
}
```

But I don't understand where in a try / catch block, where the criteria for the exception is being met. In my class we have to create our own exception, in this case the code outlined looks like:

```
public class NegativeValueException extends Exception{

    public NegativeValueException() {
            super("Numberic values must be nonnegative.");
        }

}
```

So as far as I see, there's no criteria in the code above that shows the exception should be thrown.

```
int i = 1;
try {
  i = -1; 
} catch (NegativeValueException e) {  //Thrown exception because the value is negative. 
  //Where is the criteria that catches this exception?
}
```

Comment: The `catch` _is_ the criteria. If a `NegativeValueException` is _thrown_, it will be caught.

Comment: But where is the catch defined? At what point in the code does it run through and say "okay, catching exceptions, THIS is a NegativeValueException, run this code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //Thrown exception because the value is negative.

You say this, but a `NegativeValueException` won't be thrown unless you specifically write the code to do that.

The Java compiler generates an Exception table under the hood. This table stores a mapping of `Exception` (`Throwable`) types, which lines they can occur on, and to which `catch` statement they should go to.

In your example, modified to throw the exception,

```
int i = 1; // 1
try {
     i = -1; // 2
     if (i < 0) throw new NegativeValueException(); // 3
} catch (NegativeValueException e) {  //Thrown exception because the value is negative.  // 4
  //Where is the criteria that catches this exception? // 5
}
```

Java would map something like

```
NegativeValueException - Between 2 and 3 - Goto 4
```

Now, if while executing 2 or 3, a `NegativeValueException` is thrown, the JVM will go to the exception table, figure out which statement to jump to, and do it, binding the thrown exception to the `catch` parameter.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, now is the correct way to throw custom exceptions is to put the criteria (your if statement) in the try block?

Comment: @SCHULTZ If `NegativeValueException` isn't or cannot be thrown in the `try` block, then there is no point in having a corresponding `catch` block.

Comment: Gotcha okay, really appreciate the help!